# Импорт функций из другого файла

Tags: python-3.x, импорт

Есть файл Parser.py, и в этой же папке Parsing.py. В файле Parsing.py есть метод Razbor. Создал файл __init_.py, Но в Parser.py не могу использовать метод Razbor. Вроде гуглил, ничего рабочего не мог найти. Как сделать что бы метод Razbor был виден в файле Parser.py?

Comment: Как импортируете?

Comment: from Parsing import Razbor. Так же пробовал положить Parsing в другую папку, там создать __init_.py и импортировать From NameFolder import Parsing.py

Comment: Где, относительно условного `main.py` находится папка с `Parsing.py` и `Parser.py`? Вообще, есть два пути решить эту проблему: 1 - указать правильный путь относительно запускаемого файла и 2 - перед импортом подправить переменную `sys.path`.

Comment: В этой же директории.

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял последний комментарий, то структура папок выглядит следующим образом (у меня 2-й питон, но это не имеет значения, меняется только print):

```
│   main.py
└───some
        f1.py
        f2.py
        __init__.py
```

В этом случае, правильный импорт выглядит так:
main.py:

```
from some.f1 import f1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    f1()
```

f1.py:

```
from some.f2 import f2

def f1():
    print 'f1:'
    f2()
```

f2.py:

```
def f2():
    print 'f2:'
```

вывод `python main.py`:

```
f1:
f2:
```

---

Второй способ (при той же структуре папок, main и f2.py - без изменений):

f1.py:

```
import sys
import os

sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(__file__))
import f2

def f1():
    print 'f1:'
    f2.f2()
```